# Content working fine in print but not in array

Tags: php

Currently, I am able to scrape the content from my [desired website](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-force-awakens-concept-art-rey/) without any problems, but if you view [my demo](http://news.wubstub.com/t/test.php), you can see that in my array it's only displaying **The Source** no matter what I change around, it's not fixing..

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])&&$_GET['p']!=0) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : '';  
$html = file_get_html('http://screenrant.com/movie-news/'.$page);
foreach($html->find('#site-top ul h2 a') as $element)
{
        print '<br><br>';
        echo $url = ''.$element->href;
        $html2 = file_get_html($url);
        print '<br><br>';

        $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
        print $news['image'] = $image->content;
        print '<br><br>';

        // Ending The Featured Image
        $title = $html2->find(' header > h1',0);
        print $news['title'] = $title->plaintext;

        print '<br>';
        // Ending the titles
        print '<br>';

        $articles = $html2->find('div.top-content > article > p');
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            echo "$article->plaintext<p>";
        }
        $news['content'] =  $article->plaintext;

        print '<br><br>';
        #post> div:nth-child(2) > header > p > time
        $date = $html2->find('header > p > time',0);
        $news['date'] = $date->plaintext;

        $dexp = explode(', ',$date);

        print $date = $dexp[0].', '.$dexp[1];

        print '<br><br>';

        $genre = "news";
        print '<br>';

             mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `wp_scraped_news` SET
                                    `hash` = '".$news['title']."',
                                    `title` = '".$news['title']."',
                                    `image` = '".$news['image']."',
                                    `content` = '".$news['content']."'");
             print '<pre>';print_r($news);print '</pre>';
}
```

Currently using [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do that this is not doing?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter `echo "$article->plaintext<p>";` this prints what we want it to, but when I am trying to get it inside of my array so I can deposit it to my database, it just returns **The Source** and not he entire write up like it's suppose to.

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm : try to use outertext

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I tinkered with `outertext` and `innertext` already and it does the same output.. view the updated demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at this piece of code:

```
$articles = $html2->find('div.top-content > article > p');
foreach ($articles as $article) {
   echo "$article->plaintext<p>"; 
   //This is printing the article content line by line
}
$news['content'] =  $article->plaintext; 
//This is grabbing the last line of the article content AKA the source 
//The last <p> as it's not in the foreach.
```

Effectively, you need to be doing this:

```
$articles = $html2->find('div.top-content > article > p');
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    echo "$article->plaintext<p>"; 
    $news['content'] = $news['content'] . $article->plaintext . "<p>";
}
```

Comment: If I could shake your hand, I would my friend. Thank you very much!